# Selenium test with Internet Explorer on Ubuntu

Tags: internet-explorer, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I work on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to do headless test with selenium RC.

I have install :
    - Phpunit v4.6.6
    - Php 5.5.9
    - Wine
    - ie8 with winetricks ie8

I have xvfb running.
I run selenium server 2.45

```
export DISPLAY=":99" && java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates
```

To launch my test I have a phpunit.xml (phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml) file where I define my browsers.

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true">
         <selenium>
            <browser name="Ie" browser="*custom wine 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore'" host="127.0.0.1" port="4444" timeout="30000" />
            <browser name="Chrome" browser="*googlechrome" host="127.0.0.1" port="4444" timeout="30000" />
            <browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox" host="127.0.0.1" port="4444" timeout="30000"  />
         </selenium>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Tests">
      <directory suffix=".php">tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <logging>
    <log type="junit" target="report/reportJunit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="true"/>
  </logging>
</phpunit>
```

This is not working for IE8. Firefox and Chrome work fine.Is there a way for me to run my test on Internet Explorer on Ubuntu ?
Thanks you for your help.